# Interpolate temperature time series onto a pressure grid

Tags: matlab, grid, interpolation

I have a time series with corresponding temperature and pressure values and I want to plot each temperature value at the corresponding pressure value while keeping the time series order.

I tried to interpolate the temperature values onto a pressure grid as follows,

%Lets say

```
T = temperature  (23583 x 11);
P = pressure     (23583 x 11);
t = time         (23583 x 11);
PO=min(min)(P):1:max(max)(P); (1x52) %PO=pressure grid
```

Tinterp=interp1(P,T,PO);

Gives the error:
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors must contain unique points.

Error in interp1 (line 149)
F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);

I know I have to run the interp1 function in a loop that cycles through all my columns.

```
n=23583 
for i=1:n 
    TO(i,:) = interp1(P(i,:),T(i,:),PO) 
end
```

But this has sent matlab running a continues loop for hours. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please.

I want to create a filled contour plot with PO on the Yaxis and time on the x axis and TO as my Z value.

Comment: I think you don't have enough data for such a contour plot. You need at least to be able to cover the X-Y area but you have only a trace on it, don't you?

Comment: Hi Anton actually the temperature and pressure arrays have sizes of 23583 x 11 each. The 11 represents 11 temperature recorders deployed different depths, but they move up or down with tides and as the mooring sways in the current. Hence I need have assigned a pressure value for each temperature measurement and need to interpolate this onto the pressure grid. Can you perhaps help?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand the problem now. So your plot would show how the temperature was changing for a particular pressure range over the time. Am I right? Can you may be share a part of your data so I could plot it?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do I share a .mat file on this page?

Comment: You could put the file on Google docs or some other server and post here the link.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13CEhETugoDlz_4RlIbuzEMlIPy8EdgxCWz58HuaCFT0/edit?usp=sharing                                                             
Here is the link to the sample data. Rows 1-100 are the pressure values and rows 101 -200 are the corresponding temperatures.Columns 1-11 are for different sensors.

Comment: Could you solve your problem? I got nice contour plots on your data sample, but actually my method is the same as you meant in your question.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the duplicates by using `unique` function,

```
T = randi([0 25],1,23583); % random temperature values
P = randi([800 1000],1,23583); % random pressure values
t = [1:1:23583]; % time
PO=min(P):1:max(P); %PO=pressure grid

[P, index] = unique(P); 
Tinterp=interp1(P,T(index),PO);
```